# Merge multiple csv files in google cloud storage keeping header of one file | Bash Script

Tags: bash, shell, csv, google-cloud-storage

Want to merge multiple csv files placed in google cloud storage using bash scripting.

I have created a script which is not working as it is only merging first and last file and ignores all the files in between. Like for merging 2 files its working fine but if file count increases more than 2 then it only merges file1 and file3 and simples ignores file2.

Below is the script for reference:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if the bucket name is provided as an argument
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 <bucket_name>"
  exit 1
fi

# Assign the first argument (bucket name) to BUCKET_NAME
BUCKET_NAME="$1"
STARTING_TEXT="$2"
TARGET_FILE_NAME="$3"
# Generate a timestamp
TIMESTAMP=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")

# List all files starting with 'STARTING_TEXT'
FILES=($(gsutil ls gs://$BUCKET_NAME/$STARTING_TEXT*.csv))

# Initialize the merged file with the first file's content (including header)
gsutil cp ${FILES[0]} /tmp/merged_file_with_header.csv

# Print the names of the files being merged
echo "Merging the following files:"
for FILE in "${FILES[@]}"
do
    echo "$FILE"
done

# Loop through the remaining files (starting from the second file)
for ((i=1; i<${#FILES[@]}; i++))
do
    # Download the current file without the header
    gsutil cat ${FILES[i]} | tail -n +2 > /tmp/temp_file.csv

    # Append the content to the merged file
    cat /tmp/merged_file_with_header.csv /tmp/temp_file.csv > /tmp/merged_file.csv

    # Upload the merged file back to the bucket
    gsutil cp /tmp/merged_file.csv gs://$BUCKET_NAME/$TARGET_FILE_NAME_$TIMESTAMP.csv

    # # Update the merged file with header for next iteration
    # gsutil cp gs://$BUCKET_NAME/file_with_header.csv /tmp/merged_file_with_header.csv
done
# Clean up temporary files
rm /tmp/temp_file.csv /tmp/merged_file.csv /tmp/merged_file_with_header.csv
```

Help me correct it out wherever I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment you want to **append**, but actually you overwrite:

```
cat /tmp/merged_file_with_header.csv /tmp/temp_file.csv > /tmp/merged_file.csv
```

Do a

```
cat /tmp/merged_file_with_header.csv /tmp/temp_file.csv >> /tmp/merged_file.csv
```

instead.

Comment: Thank you @user1934428. I just added this appending command(>>) and it makes sense. Anyways, I have added working script below which I just figured out.

Answer (score 0):

Working code after which I figured out, I was merging the file inside the loop which was not correct.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if the bucket name is provided as an argument
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 <bucket_name>"
  exit 1
fi

# Assign the first argument (bucket name) to BUCKET_NAME
BUCKET_NAME="$1"
STARTING_TEXT="$2"
TARGET_FILE_NAME="$3"
# Generate a timestamp
TIMESTAMP=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")

# List all files starting with 'STARTING_TEXT'
FILES=($(gsutil ls gs://$BUCKET_NAME/$STARTING_TEXT*.csv))

# Initialize the merged file with the first file's content (including header)
gsutil cp ${FILES[0]} /tmp/header.csv
sleep 5
cat /tmp/header.csv
# Print the names of the files being merged
echo "Merging the following files:"
for FILE in "${FILES[@]}"
do
    echo "$FILE"
done

#Appending file with header in merged_file which will be final output file
cat /tmp/header.csv >> /tmp/merged_file.csv

# Loop through the remaining files (starting from the second file)
for ((i=1; i<${#FILES[@]}; i++))
do
    # Download the current file without the header
    gsutil cat ${FILES[i]} | tail -n +2 > /tmp/temp_file.csv

    # Append the content to the merged file
    cat /tmp/temp_file.csv >> /tmp/merged_file.csv

    # Upload the merged file back to the bucket
    gsutil cp /tmp/merged_file.csv gs://$BUCKET_NAME/$TARGET_FILE_NAME_$TIMESTAMP.csv

done

echo "printing final file"
cat /tmp/merged_file.csv

# Clean up temporary files
rm /tmp/temp_file.csv /tmp/merged_file.csv
```

Comment: Since you're using fixed names, consider NOT appending when writing the header. `cat /tmp/header.csv > /tmp/merged_file.csv` - In fact,  this is a case where I might explicitly use a forced-truncating write just to be self-documenting: `cat /tmp/header.csv >| /tmp/merged_file.csv` (This truncates even if you have `set -o noclobber`.)